Detox: Handling iOS OS dialogs after test fail
I'm working on adding OS dialog handling to iOS e2e tests with Detox. There is however an issue where an OS permission dialog sometimes stays open after a test fails, which in turn causes any subsequent tests to fail because of the OS dialog blocking visibility of elements.
I added a workaround function that's run on beforeAll during setupAfterEnv, but while it works locally the beforeAll hook times out most of the time when being run in a pipeline environment. The function simply tries to dismiss any leftover OS dialogs with try-catch to allow the test run to continue.
Here's the code:
// Close open OS dialogs without throwing an error if not found
export const closePreviousOSDialogs = async () => {
    try {
        await expect(system.element(by.system.label('Ask App Not to Track'))).toExist();
        await system.element(by.system.label('Ask App Not to Track')).tap();
    } catch {
        // Do nothing
    }

    try {
        await expect(system.element(by.system.label('Don’t Allow'))).toExist();
        await system.element(by.system.label('Don’t Allow')).tap();
    } catch {
        // Do nothing
    }
};

beforeAll(async () => {
    await closePreviousOSDialogs();
});

The error we get in the pipeline
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 60000 ms for a hook.
Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

>  9 | beforeAll(async () => {
     | ^
  10 |     await closePreviousOSDialogs();
  11 | }, 60000);

Is there something wrong with the code that causes it to time out in the pipeline, or could there be a different solution for closing all OS dialogs?
The app is using detox: 20.27.2 and react-native: 0.75.4.
